# Combining awk search with standard awk and awk delimiter

Tags: awk

I`m working on a set of data for which I need specific fields as output:

The data looks like this:

```
/home/oracle/db.log.gz:2013-1-19T00:00:25 <user.info> 1 2013-1-19T00:00:53.911 host_name RT_FLOW [junos@26.1.1.1.2.4 source-address="10.1.2.0" source-port="616" destination-address="100.1.1.2" destination-port="23" service-name="junos-telnet" nat-source-address="20x.2x.1.2" nat-source-port="3546" nat-destination-address="9x.12x.3.0"]
```

From above I need three things:

```
(I) - 2013-1-19T00:00:53.911  which is $4 
(II)- source-address="10.1.2.0" which is $8 of which I need only 10.1.2.0
(III) - destination-address="100.1.1.2" which $10  of which I need only 100.1.1.2
```

I cannot use simple awk like this `-> awk '{ print $4 \t $8 \t $10 }'`  since there are some fields after "device_name" in the log file which are not always present in all log lines so I have to make use of delimiters such as 
`awk -F 'source-address=' '{print $2}' | awk '{print $1}`  -> this gives source-addressIP which is (II) requirement

I`m not sure how do I combine using a awk search for I and II and III.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

I believe `sed` is better for this job

```
sed -r 's/([^ ]+[ ]+){3}([^ ]+).*[ ]+source-address="([^"]+)".*[ ]+destination-address="([^"]+)".*/\2\t\3\t\4/' file
```

Output:

```
2013-1-19T00:00:53.911  10.1.2.0    100.1.1.2
```

Comment: This works like a charm! I was stuck with using awk and did not realize that sed could used. Still a newbie with both sed and awk.

Answer (score 1):

What do you exactly want?

- solve the problem using any (reasonably standard) tool
- solve this challenge using one instance of awk
- solve the problem using just awk, no matter how many instances it costs

For the first case, you could parse the line using scripting language of your choice (mine would be Perl), or do it the hard way using `sed` and a single big substitution. Or something between the two – use three regexes to get the parts you want.

For the second case, you could adapt any of the former solutions, preferably the `sed` one. Awk and sed solutions have already been posted.

For the third case, you could just run the obvious `awk` solutions you mentioned in your question and send the results to a single pipe like `{ awk …; awk …; awk …; } < file | consumer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
awk '{print gensub(/.*\s+([0-9]{4}-[0-9]+-[0-9]+T[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}.[0-9]+).*source-address="([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*destination-address="([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}).*/, "(I) \\1\n(II) \\2\n(III) \\3", "g"); }' file
```

Another solution using [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -lne 'print "(", "I" x ++$c, ")  $_" for m/.*?\s+(\d{4}-\d+-\d+T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d+).*source-address="(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*destination-address="(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}).*/' file
```

Outputs :

```
(I) 2013-1-19T00:00:53.911
(II) 10.1.2.0
(III) 100.1.1.2
```